# ASP.Net stacktrace no line number. PDB files available

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, debugging

I have an asp.net page. Sometimes i got an error with the following stacktrace.

```
   at COMPANY.EasyInvoicing.Web.BusinessLogic.PromoterProjectLocationActivityDataSourceGet(ActivityType activityType, InvoiceController invoiceController, Nullable`1 invoiceId, Boolean ignoreAlreadyInUse, Boolean receiptMandatory) in C:\Projekte\COMPANY\Promoter\EasyInvoicing\Web\BusinessLogic\1.0\BusinessLogic.cs:line 0
   at COMPANY.EasyInvoicing.Web.UI.Invoicing.ShowInvoicePositionProfessionalFeePopUp() in C:\Projekte\COMPANY\Promoter\EasyInvoicing\Web\UI\1.0\Invoicing.aspx.cs:line 142
   at COMPANY.EasyInvoicing.Web.UI.Controls.Invoicing.Invoice.professionalFeeButton_Click(Object sender, EventArgs e) in C:\Projekte\COMPANY\Promoter\EasyInvoicing\Web\UI\1.0\controls\Invoicing\Invoice.ascx.cs:line 308
   at System.Web.UI.WebControls.Button.OnClick(EventArgs e)
   at System.Web.UI.WebControls.Button.RaisePostBackEvent(String eventArgument)
   at System.Web.UI.WebControls.Button.System.Web.UI.IPostBackEventHandler.RaisePostBackEvent(String eventArgument)
   at System.Web.UI.Page.RaisePostBackEvent(IPostBackEventHandler sourceControl, String eventArgument)
   at System.Web.UI.Page.RaisePostBackEvent(NameValueCollection postData)
   at System.Web.UI.Page.ProcessRequestMain(Boolean includeStagesBeforeAsyncPoint, Boolean includeStagesAfterAsyncPoint)
```

As you can see the error occurs in "PromoterProjectLocationActivityDataSourceGet" but i can not solve it because the line number is 0.

The page is build in release mode and pdb files are deployed.

In addition, the web.config contains the following entry:

```
<compilation debug="false">
```

My first thought was to set debug="false" to true but in some methods line numbers are available and in others not. So it is not a general problem for all methods.

Can you help me?

Comment: First question, is it working in Development environment?

Comment: I cannot reproduce the error in development environment. So i dont know if it would work

Comment: Whats the error message?

Comment: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.

Comment: I have set some object in the method to zero to test it. Result: Yes it works in development environment. Line numbers are shown

Answer (score 1):

Please try the below:

Project Properties -> Build -> Advanced -> Debug Info > Set to 'full'

Comment: I'll try it. Thank you

Comment: @OPunktSchmidt did it work? If yes, please mark as answer.

Comment: This was not the solution :/

Comment: Try setting it to 'pdb-only' and then deploy the generated .pdb file. Another option to try is if you have this line in the web.config, remove it:
`<identity impersonate="true" />`

Comment: PDB files are deployed. <identity impersonate="true" /> is not in my web.config